# Creating a method of type class Matrix to add two matrices

Tags: java

so, I'm supposed to make a `matrix` using `HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<Number>>`, where Number is a class who's instance variables are numerator and denominator.
`Class Matrix` inherits `Class Number`, which have methods like `fillMatrix()`, `printMatrix()`, `addMatrix(Matrix,Matrix)` and `subMatrix(Matrix,Matrix)`, problem is in those last two methods, i made them but I'm pretty sure they are completely wrong since i get a NullPointerxception, How do i make such methods?
 here is the code.

```
 public class Matrix extends Number implements Calculation
{
public static int rows;
public static int cols;
private ArrayList<Number> myArray;
private ArrayList<Double> myArray2;
private ArrayList<Double> myArray3;
private ArrayList<Double> myArray4;
private HashMap <Integer, ArrayList<Number>> hm;
private HashMap <Integer, ArrayList<Double>> hm2;

public Matrix(int r, int c)
{
    hm = new HashMap<>();
    hm2 = new HashMap<>();
    rows = r;
    cols = c;
}
public void fillMatrix()
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    myArray = new ArrayList<>();
    myArray2 = new ArrayList<>();
    System.out.println("Enter the number of rows");
    rows = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the number of columns");
    cols = input.nextInt();
    Number n = new Number();
    for (int i = 0; i < cols;i++)
    {
        n.setNumerator(i);
        n.setDenominator(i+1);
        myArray.add(new Number(i,i+1));
        double xn = n.getNumerator();
        double xd = n.getDenominator();
         myArray2.add(xn/xd);
    }               
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    hm2.put(rows,myArray2);
}

public void printMatrix()
{ 
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {hm.put(rows,myArray);
         System.out.println(myArray3.toString());
        }
}
public Number getItem(int rowNO,int colNO)
{
    rows = rowNO - 1;
    cols = colNO - 1;
   hm.get(rows);
    return myArray.get(cols);
}
public void addMatrices(Matrix a, Matrix b)
{
   Matrix x1 = new Matrix(rows,cols);
   Matrix x2 = new Matrix(rows,cols);
   for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
   { x1.hm2.get(rows);
     x2.hm2.get(rows);
   for(int j = 0; j< cols;j++)
   {
     double a1 = x1.myArray2.get(cols);
     double a2 = x2.myArray2.get(cols);
     double sum = a1+a2;
     myArray3 = new ArrayList<>();
     myArray3.add(sum);         
   }
   x1=a;
   x2=b;
   }
}
public void subMatrices(Matrix a, Matrix b)
{
   Matrix x1 = new Matrix(rows,cols);
   Matrix x2 = new Matrix(rows,cols);
   for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
   { x1.hm2.get(rows);
   { x2.hm2.get(rows);
   for(int j = 0; j< cols;j++)
   {
     double a1 = x1.myArray2.get(cols);
     double a2 = x2.myArray2.get(cols);
     double sub = a1-a2;
     myArray4 = new ArrayList<>();
     myArray4.add(sub);         
   }
   x1=a;
   x2=b;
   }
 }

  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused here, so I'll point out some things I noticed.

First off it's difficult to understand your code because of the variable names.

Also none of the methods are static, so i don't really understand why you're bringing in two Matrices for the calculation, then setting them equal to the first two you create in the beggining of both methods.

Next, you have two brackets after your for loop in the subtraction method, I'm guessing it was just a typo when pasting in StackOverflow.

The myArray objects you're adding the sum too is not going to be accumulating all the sums because you are creating a new arraylist each time that loop goes through. Create it outside the loop.

The NullPointerException could be anywhere really, it's hard to tell because the code is a bit confusing.

**I would recommend using the LWJGL library which has has classes like `Matrix4f`and methods like `Matrix4f.add();`which will help you accomplish this.**

Answer (score 0):

Try running your program in `debug` mode so you can understand which statement gives you `null pointer exception`.

And I've noticed you have your rows and columns as static but you can change change them within constructor. It seems there is a logical mistake there. These two may be the cause of your exception if you didn't ever give initial value of them before.

If your matrixes can have different `rows` and `columns` then you definitely shouldn't use `static` for them.

To actually understand where `nullpointerexception` is given, you should also write your main code. But like I said, in debug mode, you can also see it yourself.